# Using icon packs in my app

Tags: android, android-launcher

My app includes a feature for listing all apps installed on the user's device, complete with icons. Now users request icon pack support in this list.

At the moment I list installed apps with:

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

final List<ResolveInfo> rgRi = pm.queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

and then load icons for each `ResolveInfo` with:

```
.loadIcon(application.getPackageManager());
```

This gives me the app's icon but not the icon pack one but the default one.

How do I access the icon pack icon for an app if one is available?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Answering my own question. Here is a short tutorial (complete with **pseudo-code**) on loading icons from icon packs.

### Get installed icon packs

Find apps with intent filter `com.gau.go.launcherex.theme` or `org.adw.launcher.THEMES`. Possibly others exist too.
Use e.g.

```
PackageManager.queryIntentActivities(new Intent("org.adw.launcher.THEMES"), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

### Load appfilter.xml

It can be found as a resource or in the assets folder of the icon pack. Use either

```
int i = Resources.getIdentifier("appfilter", "xml", "iconpack.package.name");
Resources.getXml(i);
```

or

```
InputStream s = iconPackres.getAssets().open("appfilter.xml");
XmlPullParserFactory f = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
f.setNamespaceAware(true);
XmlPullParser p = f.newPullParser();
p.setInput(s, "utf-8");
```

### Parse appfilter.xml

`Appfilter.xml` describes the icon pack content. Among other things the themer has the ability to draw icons on backgrounds, provide masks etc. This is all described on XDA: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1649891 . What we are most interested in is the `<item>` tags e.g.

```
<item component="ComponentInfo{com.android.browser/com.android.browser.BrowserActivity}" drawable="com_android_browser_browseractivity" />
```

The `component` attribute contains the name of the package and activity and the `drawable` is the name of the matching icon within the icon pack. Loop through the `XmlPullParser` from previous step to find the icon you want.

### Load icon

Simply get the component name for the app whose icon you want to load with

```
PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("app.package.name").getComponent().toString();
```

Than load icon with

```
Resources.getIdentifier(componentName, "drawable", "app.package.name"); 
Resources.getDrawable(...)
```

Comment: Could you have a look on my question? I tried to figure out how to load a icon pack icon based on your explanation, but I can't get it working... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490630/how-to-load-icon-from-icon-pack