# How to install icon pack on custom launcher?

Tags: java, android, android-launcher

I'm trying to install icon pack on my custom launcher, I've read this note [How to install icon pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490630/how-to-load-icon-from-icon-pack) but I'm not able to understand how to use that class, here's what I done:

```
IconPackManager ic = new IconPackManager();
HashMap<String, IconPackManager.IconPack> map = new HashMap<String, IconPackManager.IconPack>(ic.getAvailableIconPacks(false));
Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
Drawable d = null;
String packName = null;
IconPackManager.IconPack packIcon = null;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
       Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
       packName = (String)pair.getKey();
       packIcon = (IconPackManager.IconPack)pair.getValue();
       d = packIcon.getDrawableIconForPackage(packName, iconDrawable);
       setIcon(d);
    }
```

Comment: An IconPackManager is not a standard Android class. Where is the source/library information for where this class is coming from?

Comment: Above...click on how to install icon pack

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved with this:

```
String packName = null;
IconPackManager.IconPack packIcon = null;

IconPackManager ic = new IconPackManager();
HashMap<String, IconPackManager.IconPack> map = ic.getAvailableIconPacks(true);
Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();


        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            packName = (String)pair.getKey(); //Get icon pack name (app package)

            packIcon = (IconPackManager.IconPack)pair.getValue(); //Get icons

            if(packIcon.getDrawableIconForPackage("YourTargetPackageName", yourStandardIcon) != null) {

            //Your own method for set icon   
            setIcon(packIcon.getDrawableIconForPackage("YourTargetPackageName", yourStandardIcon));

            }else{
                //Your own method for set icon   
                setIcon(yourStandardIcon);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This works only if any of below packages are installed ,

1) Is it installed ?

```
org.adw.launcher.THEMES
com.gau.go.launcherex.theme
```

getAvailableIconPacks should return HashMap size >0

2) is below returning valid drawable or null?

```
 d = packIcon.getDrawableIconForPackage(packName, iconDrawable);
```

Usage is wrong in your case.

Your are iterating throw icon providers package names.SO in below case your are asking for

```
d = packIcon.getDrawableIconForPackage(packName, iconDrawable);
//means 
//d = packIcon.getDrawableIconForPackage("org.adw.launcher.THEMES",conDrawable)
```

so without above themes installation from google play it returns the default drawables only.

Comment: method had check if (!mLoaded) load(); before get drawable...so it doesn't work

Comment: I want to install icon pack (downloaded from google play) on my custom launcher, no ADW or GO, it's my launcher!
getDrawableIconForPackage return icon of "Pack Icon App"

Comment: but the IconPackManager willnot work without org.adw.launcher.THEMES
com.gau.go.launcherex.theme

Comment: maybe we're not understanding...what they need those packages?? If I download an Icon Pack from Google Play, can I install it on Launcher3 (stock launcher) through code?

Comment: packName variable of HashMap return website.leifs.delta (I have installed random icon pack) so code works..