# Change all icons of android

Tags: android, xamarin

I want to change all icons of android phone from my application project images..
Icons of google icons,youtube icons,other apps icons that has been installed in phone

how can i achieve this programatically

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of installing an icon pack and then selecting it as current icon theme?

Comment: What is your application type? What does it do?

Comment: Are you trying to create a custom launcher, or an icon pack?

Comment: I have one simple button,if i click the button it takes images from application path..and plan is to set those images as icon of apps programatically

Comment: @ManojPerumarath have one simple button,if i click the button it takes images from application path..and plan is to set those images as icon of apps programatically

Answer (score 0):

I think is possible if you develop your own Launcher application. If your application is not a louncher application it is not possible to change icons on the phone. You can read this tutorial to get an idea:

https://www.androidauthority.com/make-a-custom-android-launcher-837342-837342/

Also look at this:

[How to install icon pack on custom launcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751915/how-to-install-icon-pack-on-custom-launcher)